# Testcafe - reporter does not read options from testcaferc.json

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I've been scratching my head with this for quite a while. I want to move the reporter options from my cli/package.json command into the testcaferc.json file, e.g.

`"test:chrome:all": "testcafe chrome:headless ./src/tests/*test.ts --skip-js-errors --concurrency 4"`

testcaferc.json:

```
"reporter": [
    {
      "name": "json"
    },
    {
      "output": "./artifacts/reports",
      "pathPattern": "${DATE}/${USERAGENT}/${TIME}/${FIXTURE}/${TEST}.json"
    }
```

However when i run my script it doesn't pick up these options and therefore doesn't create the report in the specified directory.

However if I include the --reporter json command in my cli, e.g.

`"test:chrome:all": "testcafe chrome:headless ./src/tests/*test.ts --reporter json:./artifacts/reports/chrome_results.json --skip-js-errors --concurrency 4"`

When I run the test, it states
`The "reporter" options from the configuration file will be ignored.` and the report is created correctly.

So it can see them but just doesn't use them when not including --reporter json in the cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is a bug. There is a corresponding issue in the TestCafe GitHub repository: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6665